# Can't install Grakn Python client: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I am installing the latest Grakn client python with this command:

`pip3 install grakn-client`

However after a while during the install I get this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/j4/85rb7q1n55l950cyxc5h57n80000gn/T/pip-install-jx_f2vss/grpcio/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/private/var/folders/j4/85rb7q1n55l950cyxc5h57n80000gn/T/pip-install-jx_f2vss/grpcio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/j4/85rb7q1n55l950cyxc5h57n80000gn/T/pip-record-yi2uyn5w/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/grpcio Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am using Python 3.8 and Grakn 1.8.3

Answer (score 1):

For mac m1 setting variables worked for me, Used the following command:

CFLAGS="-I /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 pip pip3 install grakn-client

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem using the Grakn Python client 1.8.1 with Python 3.8.x, so please downgrade your Python to 3.7 or lower for now - this issue should be fixed soon.